# Update property values using the ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The ViewModel below is used on multiple forms.

My goal is to update values received from those forms using the DateRangeViewModel itself. Is it possible?

Example: User submits *"2022-01-01 12:00:00 AM"* and I update it to *"2022-01-02 12:00:00 AM"* before passing it to the controller.

What I have tried:

```
public class DateRangeViewModel
{
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { 
        get 
        {
            if (!To.HasValue) { return null; }
            return To.Value.AddDays(1);
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```

And it throws an Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'.

I know I can update these values through the controller. However, it is not my intent.

Comment: Convert it to full property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backing field:

```
public class DateRangeViewModel
{   
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { 
        get 
        {
            return _to;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                _to = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _to = value.Value.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime? _to;
}
```

Probably it would be clearer, if you use an additional Property:

```
public class DateRangeViewModel
{   
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToPlus1Day => To == null ? null : To.Value.AddDays(1)
}
```

Comment: +1 for the additional Property - I didn't mention that, but it could save a lot of confusion in the long run

Comment: Thanks it worked. The AddDays(1) was just an example of what I wanted to achieve. Great suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically creating a recursive function here (hence the StackOverflowException). You don't need to reference "To" inside the getter, you need to reference "an internal value" (most likely private).

So this should work:

```
private DateTime? ToValue { get; set; }
public DateTime? To 
{
    get { return ToValue.HasValue ? ToValue.AddDays(1) : null; }
    set { ToValue = value; }
}
```